# IPA bundle does not include a Payload directory

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Что означает эта фраза?

Я залил свою программу в `Itunesconnect`, и через время получил на почту сообщение:

> Invalid Bundle Structure - Your package contains a bundle with the following issue: IPA bundle does not include a Payload directory.

Заливал через органайзер.
Что это означает?
Как решить это дело?

Comment: перевод не помогает?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194582/invalid-binary-error Посмотрите, не Ваш случай?